# How to automatically select in Shutter without having to confirm the selection with enter?

Tags: screenshot, shutter

I use Shutter with its selection tool that asks me to draw my selection. Then I need to press enter to confirm the selection. Gnome Screenshot, for example, automatically takes the current selection by releasing the mouse key. I want this very same behaviour.

Is there any setting I may have overlooked that automatically confirms the selection without me having to press enter?

This is a screenshot of the selection tool that doesn't proceed until I press enter:

[image]

Comment: How else will the software know what your actual selection is?

Comment: I agree, it should take the shot on release of the mousebutton, signaling you have finished making the selection. (Configurable behaviour). Unfotunately, I think your stuck with pressing enter.

Comment: @Graham clarified in my question.

Comment: @orschiro Thanks. I'll  post that as an answer so you can mark it off.

Comment: @Graham ok great!